# implement java deserialization in pure python with python-javaobj?

Tags: java, python, serialization, sqlite, db4o

i am doing reverse engineering on android app. and need to deserialize a sqllite3 blob data which is serialized in android com.db4o class.

found python-javaobj project on code google site. http://code.google.com/p/python-javaobj/

but implementing is little tricky.

## Method 1. Access with sqllite in python.

```
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect('sqlite3.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('select binaryfield from sqltable')
blob=c.fetchone()
blobstring=blob[0]
import javaobj
marshaller = javaobj.loads(blobstring)
```

Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/javaobj-0.1.0-py2.6.egg/javaobj.py", line 44,         in loads
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/javaobj-0.1.0-py2.6.egg/javaobj.py", line 155, in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/javaobj-0.1.0-py2.6.egg/javaobj.py", line 178, in _readStreamHeader
IOError: The stream is not java serialized object. Invalid stream header: 00000005
```

I am wondering is there any other approaches.

Comment: Wouldn't that be much, much, muuuuch simpler with Jython in general? Anyways I'd first check whether the object was really serialized with the standard serialization protocol, which obviously is simplest by just writing a java program (though the protocol is open and not that complicated)

Comment: yes, i would like to use jython. but my production environment does not support java. I would try the latter sugeestion. thanks.

Comment: The blob you're reading from the sqlite3 db may not be the serialized object, or maybe there were bytes added onto it. You may need to inspect the data in the DB and what's being returned from the query to be sure it's a serialized java obj.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach, in the context that you don't mention the context of your question:

- Create a helper script in Java
- The script reads the serialized object (Note that you need Java class code for this)
- Export data using a common format like JSON

Comment: thank you for reply. but I want some more usage example for that python-javaovj package and find out whats wrong.